# Threads behaving in the opposite way of what I though to be

Tags: java, multithreading, random, time, runnable

Just importing random numbers and counting no. of negatives , even_positive , even_negative ;
Task is to see multithreading work reducing execution time;
By)
performing same task in main function and by multithreading;

Code 1)
In first I create a single class implementing `Runnable`. That single class does all the counting job. But according to me each function (talking about function call inside `run()` method) is executing when previous function ends and hence should even increase the time since we are looping 3 times to get the same data. But to my surprise the execution time is less than simply counting through one loop in main function;

Code 2)

In second case I created 3 class implementing `Runnable` interface so that all my process can be concurrent and hence should have reduced time. But to my surprise opposite happens. It takes more time than the single loop in main function for the same task;

```
import java.util.Random;

class ThreadClass implements Runnable {
    private int[] random;

    public ThreadClass(int[] a) {
        random=a;
    }

    int neg(int[] random) {
        int nega=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
            if (random[i] < 0)
                nega++;
        }
        return nega;
    }

    int posiEven(int[] random) {
        int posEven=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
            if (random[i] > 0){
                if(random[i]%2==0)
                    posEven++;
            }
        }
        return posEven;
    }

    int posiOdd(int[] random) {
        int posOdd=0;
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++) {
            if (random[i] > 0){
                if(random[i]%2!=0)
                    posOdd++;
            }
        }
        return posOdd;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("negative, positive odd, positive even "+neg(random)+" "+posiOdd(random)+" 
"+posiEven(random));
    }
}   

public class Lab6_Q2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] random = new int[10000];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            random[i]=r.nextInt(201)-100;
        }
        int neg=0,posEven=0,posOdd=0;
        long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
            if(random[i]<0)
                neg++;
            else{
                if(random[i]%2==0)
                    posEven++;
                else
                    posOdd++;
            }
        }
        long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("negative, positive odd, positive even "+neg+" "+posOdd+" "+posEven);
        System.out.println("Time taken without using multiple threads: "+(endTime1-startTime1)+" ns");

        ThreadClass threadClass = new ThreadClass(random);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(threadClass);
        long startTime2 = System.nanoTime();
        t1.start();
        long endTime2 = System.nanoTime();

        System.out.println("Time taken  using multiple threads: "+(endTime2-startTime2)+" ns");
    }
}
```

Code 2)

```
import java.util.Random;

class Negative implements Runnable
{
private int[] random;
int neg;
public Negative(int[] a)
{
    random=a;
    neg= 0;
}
public void run()
{
    
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
    {
        System.out.println("in_negative");
        if (random[i] < 0)
            neg++;
    }
}
}

class Positive_even implements Runnable
{
    private int random[];
    int pos_even;

public Positive_even(int a[])
{
    random = a;
    pos_even = 0;
    
}
    public void run()

        {
          for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
          {
              System.out.println("in_pos_even");
                if (random[i] > 0)
                {
                if(random[i]%2==0)
                    pos_even++;
            }
         }
    }
}

class positive_odd implements Runnable
{
    private int random[];
    int pos_odd;

    public positive_odd(int a[])
{
    random = a;
    pos_odd = 0;
}
public void run()
{
      for(int i=0;i<10;i++) 
      {
          System.out.println("in_pos_odd");
            if (random[i] > 0)
            {
                if(random[i]%2 != 0)
                    pos_odd++;
            }
        }
}                                         
}
public class Lab6_Ques2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[] random = new int[10];
        Random r = new Random();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            random[i]=r.nextInt(20)-10;
         }
    int neg=0,posEven=0,posOdd=0;
    long startTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        if(random[i]<0)
            neg++;
        else{
            if(random[i]%2==0)
                posEven++;
            else
                posOdd++;
        }
    }
    long endTime1 = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("negative, positive odd, positive even "+neg+" "+posOdd+" "+posEven);
    System.out.println("Time taken without using multiple threads: "+(endTime1-startTime1)+" ns");
                                                   
    Negative threadClass1 = new Negative(random); 
    Thread t1 = new Thread(threadClass1); 
     
    Positive_even threadClass2 = new Positive_even(random);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(threadClass2);
    
    positive_odd threadClass3 = new positive_odd(random);
    Thread t3 = new Thread(threadClass3);
    
    long startTime2 = System.nanoTime(); 
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    long endTime2 = System.nanoTime(); 
                                                                         
    System.out.println("Time taken  using multiple threads: "+(endTime2-startTime2)+" ns");
}
}
```

Comment: Using multiple threads does not always reduce the time taken to complete the work. It takes time to create and launch threads and you have no control over that. When you have large amounts of data to process, using multiple threads may reduce the overall time.

Comment: Measuring the time taken for [java] code to execute is not simple or straightforward. Measuring execution time is known as "benchmarking". There are many online examples of how it should be done.

Comment: It looks like in both versions you are doing `tX.start();` (starting the thread) but you are not waiting for the execution of those threads to finish (e.g. using 1Thread#join`). Meaning if you print something at the end of those threads, that'll probably appear after you last System.out.